# Maximal polyhedra of a polyhedral complex

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polyhedra, tropical-geometry

According to this paper by Diane Maclagan (https://arxiv.org/abs/1207.1925, p.10), a polyhedral complex is pure if the dimension of every maximal polyhedron is the same, which is shown in the figure 11. [image]

However, I don't understand why the complex on the left is pure and the one on the right isn't pure. I assumed that we are only talking about the grey-ish areas; so, on the left, I thought the maximal polyhedra would be the ones more in the center. But according to this theory, I would only have one polyhedron on the right and this would be maximal as the only one?!

So, it would be great if anyone could solve my (possible) misunderstanding of "maximal polyhedra" and additionally explain the figure. Thank you!

Comment: The single edge going from the middle-right to down-right is a maximal face of dimension 1, while there is above a maximal face of dimension 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Points inside the 2 lower edges in the right pic do not belong to any gray face. Thus the local dimension is just 1 (at maximum). Whereas all other edges (in fact of both pics) belong at least to one gray face at minimum. Thus their local maximal dimension is 2. Therefore in the left pic all points belonging to the structure do have maximal dimension 2, whereas in the right pic some points have maximal dimension 1, others 2.

--- rk

Comment: First of all, thank you! But I think I have a misunderstanding about the above picture: They are polyhedral complexes, i.e. they consist of polyhedrons. Now I thought that means we only look at the grey areas and in order to get their dimension, I would need to calculate the dimension of their affine hull. From your answer, I deduce that the edges also belong to the polyhedral complex? And are they polyhedrons themselves? (As I do know that a face of dimension $1$ is an edge, this would make sense...but why are they maximal?)

Comment: Just as face either is being used to name a 2D boundary element and some times is used to describe any $d$-dimensional boundary element, so too polyhedron is sometimes used to name the 3D polytope and sometimes used to describe any $d$-dimensional polytope. Esp. within the combination "polyhedral complex" this term is more meant to refer to the Notion of complexes in an polyhedral / polytopal sense, rather than to the concrete dimensionality.

Comment: A point clearly is 0-dimensional. A point within an edge has a 1-dimensional local environment. A point within an edge, which is incident to a face, has a 2-dimensional local environment. - Therefore the attribute "maximal" is being used here to refer to the maximal dimension of the local environment of a point within the structure.